# Materializecss - Remove on <a> Click SideNav Overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

i'm using this Javascript Code to close the SideNav:

```
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
 closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
 }
);
```

For the SideNav it works fine but after closing the SideNav the Overlay is still there. Cause Javascript of Materialize will create the element

`<div id="sidenav-overlay" style="opacity: 1;" class=""></div>`

It would be great if could get a fast solution.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are missing something it working fine here www.jsfiddle.net/cuxzdkzr/

Comment: if you are still facing issue see here for more https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sidenav++overlay

Answer (score 0):

The reason there are multiple overlays appearing behind your SideNav is because materialize's `$('.button-collapse').sideNav()` is being run multiple times on the same element.

A quick fix for this is to remove all previous `click()` events from your element before re-initializing materialize's sideNav, like so:

```
$(".button-collapse").off('click').sideNav({ --yourOptions-- });
```